# Comparing Strings in Excel Returns Unexpected False

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of mostly identical strings in excel (including identical case), one is pasted from a CSV file and one is from an XLS file.

If I run EXACT, or just =, or =if(A1=B1,true,false) I always get a negative (false) value. Is this an issue with formats? What can I do to achieve the expected result?

Comment: You can get hidden characters with cut-and-paste in Excel. Spaces in particular can be two different characters, one of which is a space and the other just looks like a space.

Comment: I agree with the above comments. I suggest you try this free *cellview* addin from [Chip Pearsons site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CellView.aspx) to identify the differing characters. CHAR(160) being the likely culprit

Comment: you get a negative value rather than a true or false as per your formula?

Comment: By negative I meant false, wrote this while half asleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing from CSV create sometime some formatting problem, for example extra spaces o other char!

Comment: I saved the file in XLS format (instead of CSV) and EXACT now works as expected.

Comment: @AndrewBarinov but what was your actual issue?

Comment: The file was in a csv when I was comparing two seemingly identical strings and the comparison returned that they were unequal, when I saved it into xls that comparison then returned true.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try Trim() Function to filter out extra space in the left or right ?

Comment: running =len on both XLS and CSV cells returns the same number so there's no extra spaces